# What do the "#" and "!#" mean when selecting entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen `#` and `!#` show up before `minecraft:entity` when I'm typing a command to kill or teleport all of one mob. What do they mean? I experimented with

```
/kill @e[type=!#minecraft:skeletons]
```

and

```
/kill @e[type=#minecraft:skeletons]
```

But they both end up with everything dying; not just skeletons, and it includes me. Is this a bug, or am I not using it right? Below is a picture of what I mean:

[image: What is this?]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minecraft has a set of pre-defined tags (or groups) for entities, blocks, items, etc. These tags allow you to select multiple types of entities (or other mentioned types) at the same time.

The "#" prefix indicates that you are referencing a tag. For example, "#minecraft:arrows" will target all arrow types (normal arrows and spectral arrows). The exclamation mark before the "#" prefix is used in combination with the equal sign to invert the condition.

- "=" means "is equal"
- "=!" means "is not equal"

So "type=!#minecraft:arrows" will target every entity that is not an arrow. You can find more info about tags on [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag) wiki page.

Comment: Any idea why the skeleton selector in the question still targets everything, even if it’s not a skeleton?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 taking a guess, if I am understanding this right, looking at the wiki for [entity tags](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tag#Entity_type_tags), the syntax needs to be `#(namespaced ID)`.  The namespaced ID for [skeletons](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Skeleton#Data_values) is `skeleton` (not plural, where as in the OP it is).  Thus because the OP is using the plural form, the condition is never met (since `skeletons` isn't the namespace ID), and it still kills skeletons in both cases.

Comment: @TimmyJim `skeletons` is in the list tho just do CTRL+F. Also you seem to be talking about the entity itself, while this is talking about tags

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I did a few tests to make sure it's not a bug, and both selectors worked as intended. I think the OP mixed them up or made a typo.

Comment: @MegaCrafter10 I was just confused about it, and now I know the reason why is because the "!" means "everything except this" .

Comment: As somebody used to `!=` as operator for _not equal to_, I can see how `=!` can be wrongly parsed (and understood).

Comment: @kiamlaluno but even then `abc=!x` is still the opposite of x, so I'm confused as to what you mean?

Comment: @Penguin In some languages, `abc=!x` would set `abc` to a Boolean value depending on which value `x` has, which is different from what `abc != x` in those languages means.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes abc=!x always sets the opposite of x and abc!=x always returns whether x does not equal abc or not